# Is it possible to DRY this migration up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration, dry

I have a table, folders that I want some other tables to reference, so far my migration script looks like this:

```
create_table :folders do |t|
  t.timestamps
end

....

change_table table1 do |t|
  t.references :folders
end
change_table table2 do |t|
  t.references :folders
end
change_table table3 do |t|
  t.references :folders
end
change_table table4 do |t|
  t.references :folders
end
```

Since I'm doing essentially the same thing to each table, is there a more concise and maintainable way to write this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
[table1, table2, table3, table4].each do |tbl|
    change_table tbl { |t| t.references :folders }
end
```

I hope you don't name tables with pattern `table{#n}` and give them good names in your actual code :)

Comment: Yeah, those names were just for the purpose of abstract example :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this.

```
  (1..4).each do |num|
      change_table "table#{num}" do |t|
      t.references :folders
      end
    end
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: You would need to eval that string, otherwise it simply stays a string; it's not something that points to a table# object.